# TypeError: $location.path is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<span class="button-icon pull-left" ><i class="ti ti-plus" ng-click="itemOpen()"></i></span>
```

This is my Html Code.

```
 $scope.itemOpen=function()
         {
             return $location.path('/ConsultationParameterMaster');
         };
```

This is my script. 
And the error is. 
[$location.path is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc3gA.jpg)

Comment: did you inject $location in your controller?

Comment: coreModule.registerController('MedicalRecordsController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', 
        'Restangular', '$element', '$themeModule', '$filter', '$uibModal', 'gettext', 'focus', '$location',
            function ($rootScope, $scope, $sessionStorage, Restangular, $element, $theme, $filter, $modal, gettext,$location,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to inject $location in your controller if you are going to do this. where you are missing 'focus' as a parameter

```
app.controller('sampleController', ['$scope','$http','$location', function($scope,$http,$location) {
 $scope.itemOpen=function()
         {
             return $location.path('/ConsultationParameterMaster');
         };
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to your comment,You need to arrange the dependencies,

```
coreModule.registerController('MedicalRecordsController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', 'Restangular', '$element', '$themeModule', '$filter', '$uibModal', 'gettext', 'focus', '$location', function ($rootScope, $scope, $sessionStorage, Restangular, $element, $themeModule, $filter, $uibModal, gettext,focus,$location)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.controller('ctrl', ['$http','$scope','$location', function($http,$scope,$location) {
 $scope.itemOpen=function()
         {
             return $location.path('/ConsultationParameterMaster');
         };
}
```

```html
<span class="button-icon pull-left" ><i class="ti ti-plus" ng-click="itemOpen()"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should take `$location` as an argument. If you forgot to inject `$location`, you obviously can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript, whereever your angular controller is defined, you need to inject dependency for `$location`, like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies aren't lined up correctly. You have `'focus'` in the dependency list but not in the parameter list, so your `$location` is actually `focus`. That's why it doesn't have a `.path()` method.

To fix, add `focus` to your parameters:

```
$modal, gettext, /*-->*/focus/*<--*/, $location)
```